# how to convert BitmapDescriptor to drawable in android for imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

Hi i am developing mapview using v2,

From MarkerOptions object i am getting an icon, like...

```
MarkerOptions mo = markersList.get(pos);
BitmapDescriptor icon = mo.getIcon(); //Gets the custom icon set for this MarkerOptions object.

ImageView logo;

//how to assign icon to textview like using below code
logo.setBackgroundResource(icon) // It is not taking directly (BitmapDescriptor icon)
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to do this?

Comment: @Noel Nope, Not able to do that. I left it.